# Looking to find the minimum date given two columns (name and date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in MS SQL with two columns of names and dates, similar to below.

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2020 |
| A | 2/1/2020 |
| A |  |
| B | 1/1/2020 |
| B | 2/1/2020 |
| C | 1/1/2020 |
| C | 2/1/2020 |
| C |  |

I am using the query below but it is bringing back blank values for minimum values. Is there a better way to run the query so I can get the earliest date for each individual?

```
SELECT name, MIN(date)
FROM dbo.T
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Your code does what you want. For this sample data, it would not return "blank" values for the minimum date - which makes your question unclear.

Comment: Blank or NULL ?   If blank, then is your date stored as a string and NOT a date?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are storing the dates as a string

Perhaps something like this

```
SELECT name, MIN(try_convert(date,[date]))
FROM dbo.T
Where try_convert(date,[date]) is not null
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: It's better to redesign such storage, because basically you cannot say what is `1/2/2020`: is it `2020-01-02` or `2020-02-01`. And you'll never find that wrongly converted or inserted dates.

Comment: @astentx No doubt, but that might not be an option.  This may be how OP is receiving the data.    Over the years I've had to consume some horrible data.  Yes, ambiguous dates are a pet peeve of my, but I did assume M/D/Y.  If not it would be a small matter to Set DateFormat DMY.